# Phonegap 2.3 watchposition ios Background data upload to server

Tags: ios, cordova, upload, geolocation, position

i have created an phonegap app for IOS that tracks the position of the user. At this time it is possible to use it in the Background. But if i like to upload theses data to an Server it will only work when the app is in the foreground.

Is it possible to call a js function in the Background or another way to transfer theses data to an REST Server in an continous Intervall, when the app is in the background?

I has searched for many times about this problem and i can't meantion that nobody has it in the past. I read many about plugins for phone gap, but don't understand how to create on that could help me.

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

In short no - IOS only has limited background processing for 3rd party apps.

You can get limited background processing with a VOIP app or using push notifications but I guess this isn't suitable for you